# Are questions in the form/manner "How can I get started in [sport]?" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic, asking-questions

I had assisted in narrowing the scope of this question: [What kite-surfing equipment should I start with?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/what-kitesurfing-equipment-should-i-start-with),  <strike>this question:  https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3783</strike> , and this question: [how to jump on a snowboard - beginner](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/4810). However, there still has been input in regards to these questions being [too broad](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

On the contrary, similar and (arguably) less narrow questions were received favorably: [How can I get started in golf?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/992/how-can-i-get-started-in-golf) and [How to start with halfpipe snowboarding?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/how-to-start-with-halfpipe-snowboarding) and [Archery for beginners](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2550) and [Learning Cricket](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4753/learning-cricket) and [Learning ski jumping](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/611/learning-ski-jumping)

**Are questions in the form/manner "How can I get started in [sport]?" on-topic?** If so, how should one approach asking this type of question?

Comment: Looking for answers from those who think these questions are too broad. Help Sports SE define its scope!

Answer (score 3):

I skipped that close review post, because I was having second thoughts, only to realize this meta post afterwards.

What strikes me is that people find the question *too broad*, but fail to edit the question. I thought the request itself was pretty clear, but with too much text.

I reviewed the question (edited) and in this state, I find the question Sports beta worthy. I hope it will attract people, that "speak" from first hand and not just people searching for and internet answer.

Comment: Agreed. The main point here is that if a question needs to be improved, improve it. If it's "too broad," wheres the reasoning or the assistance to improve it?

Comment: I like your last point because first-hand experience outweighs research in such questions.

Comment: So true. In regards to many sports, someone who has played it before and knows what it requires will give a much more thorough answer than just looking at a list of rules or guidelines.

Comment: Just an aside, it appears answers based on experience need sources as such answers have an "inherent weakness" in that they cannot be verified. I defended against it [here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/14200), because I don't agree (as SE is a site for experts, so expertise and experience is much appreciated).